# extract the top-level domain and the second-level domain from a URL

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I'd like to extra the top-level domain and the second-level domain from a URL like "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask"

Example URL with desired result below.

```
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
   stackexchange.com

https://www.nytimes.com/2019/07/16/science/5g-cellphones-wireless-cancer.html
   nytimes.com

https://nextdoor.com/news_feed/?post=117602&ct=-A17-ghvVOF0tfn9vptW_5a7JOBEyP4w6_hJAZUnMQqN56952&ec=OWKiQRDj9vEHefhwfGYAE0s%3D&lc=1002&is=tpe
   nextdoor.com

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007B60SCG/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1
   amazon.com

http://www.verizon.net/index.php
   verizon.net
```

I'm ignoring those multi-tier domains. I'd prefer to use Bash on macOS.

There are lots of pages on getting the full domain name:

1. Extract domain name from URL using bash shell parameter substitution

   https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/get-extract-domain-name-from-url-in-linux-unix-bash/
2. `echo http://example.com/index.php | awk -F[/:] '{print $4}'`

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/11385736/1360075

I do not need this level of perfection.

https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract

Comment: If no one has an answer after a couple days, consider adding a small edit with a table of 3 or 4 examples what top/second actually mean. The library you mention has a lookup table so we don’t know if you care about a pattern or just a smaller lookup table?

Comment: Do you only need to extract `.com` domain names? Are you concerned about multi-tier domains, such as `.co.uk`?

Comment: I didn't have any idea of what the components of a URL were called. In my looking around these forum, domain name seemed to include www.example.com which I didn't want.  I wanted just example.com.  I turned to google where I found those names.  There doesn't seem to be a uniform definition of the components. https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/  and https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url and https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url For some reason, folks in the UK are most prolific with the explaination of URL components, but they have the funny names too.

Comment: A domain name is just that, a name. The only truly standardized part is the last element (TLD, top level domain), everything else is just a group of strings concatenated by '.'  The UK and some other countries have a second layer „beneath“ the TLD, but even is just a convention.

Comment: See https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3986 for the formal definition and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier for a more approachable description of the URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are already using `awk` and are looking for a simple solution:

```
awk -F/ '{n=split($3, a, "."); printf("%s.%s", a[n-1], a[n])}' <<< 'http://www.example.com/index.php'
      ^ ^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      | |          |                                  |
      | |          |                            last two elements 
      | |          |
      | |          +--- Split the 3rd field (aka the part after //) into
      | |               the array 'a', using '.' as the separator for splitting.
      | |               Returns the number of created array elements in 'n'.
      | |
      | +-------------- The awk code between the '' gets run once for every
      |                 input line, with the fields split by -F/ stored in
      |                 $1, $2 etc. In our case $1 contains "http:", $2 is 
      |                 empty, $3 contains "www.example.com" and $4 etc. the
      |                 various path elements (if there are any)
      |
      +---------------- Split the input lines into fields, separated by '/'
```

Comment: One line & one command:  !

Comment: You might add a newline character to printf - `printf("%s.%s\n"` and could you explain how your solution works ?

Comment: @fd0 Depends on what you want to do with the result afterwards. If you assign it to a variable you don't want to have a trailing newline.

Comment: @Dan I see a ; in the one line, but I see it's in single quotes, so I guess it squeaks by.  Whatever, it's short and understandable after reading the explanation.

Comment: @historystamp the `;` is the `awk` line separator, and here it is read by `awk` and not the shell because the whole `awk` script is the part between the `'`.

Comment: @user3439894 It started out as a regexp, but you're right. In the current form the backslash isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

## Parsing URLs with Bash

The following questions should provide a good starting point:

- [Parse URL in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174220/parse-url-in-shell-script)
- [Parse below URL in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378663)

[@pjz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17287984/295396) breaks apart a URL into more manageable parts:

```
#!/bin/sh

INPUT_URL="https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007B60SCG/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1"

# extract the protocol
proto="`echo $INPUT_URL | grep '://' | sed -e's,^\(.*://\).*,\1,g'`"
# remove the protocol
url=`echo $INPUT_URL | sed -e s,$proto,,g`

# extract the user and password (if any)
userpass="`echo $url | grep @ | cut -d@ -f1`"
pass=`echo $userpass | grep : | cut -d: -f2`
if [ -n "$pass" ]; then
    user=`echo $userpass | grep : | cut -d: -f1`
else
    user=$userpass
fi

# extract the host -- updated
hostport=`echo $url | sed -e s,$userpass@,,g | cut -d/ -f1`
port=`echo $hostport | grep : | cut -d: -f2`
if [ -n "$port" ]; then
    host=`echo $hostport | grep : | cut -d: -f1`
else
    host=$hostport
fi

# extract the path (if any)
path="`echo $url | grep / | cut -d/ -f2-`"

echo $hostport
```

Given the `$hostport`, you should now be able to strip back the domain as desired.

Comment: "Given the $hostport".  I could have hacked something together, but it would not have been elegant.

Comment: If you need a robust solution, use an existing URL parsing library. If you need something to pass over a set of constrained URLs once, a Bash script is a reasonable choice.